# Implementation of the roller constraint

Tags: finite-element, constrained-optimization

What could be the best way to implement the roller constraint in finite element code, i.e. constraint of the type

$$\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{n} = 0$$

I plan to enforce it in the weak sense by incorporating

$$\int_\Gamma \lambda \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{n} \, dA$$

into the weak form. However, it needs to define the Lagrange multiplier at the node, which will increase the system size.

Comment: For what problem? The answer might be very different for, say, the Euler equations vs the Stokes equations.

Comment: This type of constraint is usually implemented by performing a coordinate transformation at the roller node so that the direction **n** is along one of the coordinate axes. Then a zero constraint is applied in the usual way to that DOF.

Comment: You might find https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/36432/inclined-general-dirichlet-boundary-conditions useful

Comment: @BillGreene I'm looking for the roller constraint on a cylinder surface. I think nodal constraint does not work for that case.

Comment: Are you doing a linear or nonlinear analysis? If linear, just create a coordinate system with an axis normal to the surface and constrain that dof.

Comment: @BillGreene nonlinear dynamics analysis eventually